# Having trouble with the Baker Framework

Tags: objective-c

I am looking for someone that may be able to point me in the right direction.  They will need to be familiar with the Baker Framework though.

When I compile and run the app, I select the subscribe button.  This gives a little popover list.  It lists all of the subscription options I have setup in iTunes.  Currently it is showing the Product ID for the subscription i.e.. com.website.product  I want it to show what it really is such as 30 Days.

Any ideas of where I can find the code to do this.  Or how I should go about doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I located area and have included the code below.  In the ShelfViewController.m you need to locate the following function:

```
- (UIActionSheet *)buildSubscriptionsActionSheet
```

Once you have located that I created a new string variable to hold what I wanted to display and then added the following code:

```
if (!purchasesManager.subscribed) {
    if ([FREE_SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID length] > 0 && ![purchasesManager isPurchased:FREE_SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID]) {
        [sheet addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"SUBSCRIPTIONS_SHEET_FREE", nil)];
        [actions addObject:FREE_SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID];
    }

    for (NSString *productId in AUTO_RENEWABLE_SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_IDS) {
        NSString *title = NSLocalizedString(productId, nil);
        NSString *price = [purchasesManager priceFor:productId];
        if ([title  isEqual: @"com.website.90days"]){
            title2 = @"3 Months";
        }
        if ([title  isEqual: @"com.website.180days"]){
            title2 = @"6 Months";
        }
        if ([title  isEqual: @"com.website.365days"]){
            title2 = @"1 Year";
        }
        if (price) {
            [sheet addButtonWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", title2, price]];
            [actions addObject:productId];
        }
    }
}
```

That will allow you to make the action sheet say whatever you want while still sending the proper identifier to the purchasing Mechanism.